# PROBLEMA CON GCM EN LINUX

Tags: android, linux

Al ejecutar un jar que me sirve para enviar un pushin mediante GCM en WINDOWS no tengo problemas pero al ejecutar mi jar en LINUX me salta el siguiente error :

> 1 [main] ERROR MAIN  - IO Exception java.net.ConnectException: Expiró
>   el tiempo de conexión
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
>           at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:275)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>           at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
>           at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
>           at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
>           at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
>           at MAIN.main(MAIN.java:41)

Comment: Una duda ¿El error que te da es en tu aplicación andorid o de tu jar que esta en ejecución? Si es en la app, y dices que en windows funciona bien, puede ser que el puerto al que quieres conectarte no este abierto. Pero danos mas detalles para que te podamos ayudar mas

Comment: Tú no codificaste el `jar`, ¿verdad?

Comment: Al ver este error - IO Exception java.net.ConnectException y si indicas que en otra pc te funciona correctamente, me parece que es problema de algún puerto bloqueado o tu firewall, prueba deshabilitandolo.

Comment: Si este error solo me pasa al ejecutarlo en un sistema operativo LINUX en el windows no tengo problemas es al ejecutar el jar... como puedo comprarbar que sea el firewall del sistema LINUX? alguna recomendaricion les dejo mas informacion o algo al respecto para ayudarlos? soy nuevo en la comunidad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

A nivel de seguridad, dependiendo de la distribución en la que te encuentres,
por ejemplo en centos, redhat, puedes verificar si el puerto que buscas está arriba con este comando:

```
netstat -nap | grep :puerto
```

Ejemplo:

```
netstat -nap | grep :1234
```

Para verificar el firewall, si estas en versión 6:

```
service iptables status
```

en version 7

```
systemctl status firewalld.service
```

También debes verificar el SELinux, si está habilitado.

Para verificarlo escribes `getenforce`

```
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
```

Si está en `enforcing`  prueba pasándolo a `permissive` , esto se hace con el comando

```
setenforce 0
```